# Looking for a sci fi story with bio augmentation and hoopers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I think I read this as a young teen many decades ago (I am 54)

Two men were doing space adventure stuff. He's bio augmented but can only activate it for short periods and a fungus is mentioned that causes green bands "hoops" to show on the infected. You can tell how dangerous a hooper is by the amount of green skin spread from the infection site.

Hoopers are depicted as being pain resistant and very very hard to kill until they get exposed to a "bloom" of the fungus and they die messily as they "spore". Hoopers are depicted as taking part in blood sports etc.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. I'm honestly not 100% on my answer now, but just in case someone posts something better.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like Neil Asher's *[The Polity](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/ThePolity)* series.

> The stories follow three plotlines. The first, occurring in the 2400s is centered around the Earth Central Security Agent Ian Cormac, and later his allies that have managed to survive at least 2 books. The second, set in the 31st Century, is centered around three travelers to the primitive world of Spatterjay and its notoriously deadly seas. The third takes place sometime between the two, following around the rogue AI war drone Penny Royal.

....

> Took a Level in Badass: Ian Cormac takes this in epic levels. Mr. Crane, as if he isn't scary enough being able to swim in lava as if it's water, But is later modified by a Dragon Sphere to be able to subvert and control Jain Technology without being infected.
>
> - Logically, it should extend to any non-native of Spatterjay who gets infected with the Hooper virus. Nothing says Badass more than having a localized sport that requires you to remove at least a meter of uninterrupted intestine without the opponent removing both your eyes or the two of you both passing out from bloodloss.

From this Encyclopedia entry on the [Spatterjay virus](https://www.nealasher.co.uk/polity-encyclopaedia/):

> Spatterjay Virus: Many questions surround this virus and its relationship with the leeches, and few of them can be answered. There is little fossil evidence of leeches, for obvious reasons, and that of viral growth in other life-forms tells us only when it began to appear, and then only to the nearest hundred million years. Genetic archaeology is also of little use, since the virus is an eclectic collector of Spatterjay’s equivalent of DNA from the planet’s biosphere.
>
> Terran viruses, upon entering a cell, propagate from it and destroy it in the process. The Spatterjay virus roots in it and grows as a fibre to other cells, gradually networking the host body in a fibrous mass. These cells are then maintained perpetually. But the virus also engineers the DNA. Should the animal be damaged, or its environment change, the virus will alter its host to the optimum for survival in those circumstances. An animal can have its head cut off and yet not die; the virus will stimulate it to grow the necessities of survival. The usual result of this is the body growing a leech’s plug-cutting mouth, probably because the bulk of additional DNA the virus carries is of the leech, its original host. In this manner the virally infected prey become a perpetually reusable food resource for the leeches themselves. So it would seem that when the virus appeared, the leeches swiftly took advantage of it.
>
> Humans, being ill-suited to Spatterjay’s biosphere, are quickly adapted by the virus, unless they take preventive measures. Hoopers stave off the ‘change’ by eating Terran foods which, lacking in nutrition for the virus, very much slow its growth. Drugs such as Intertox also inhibit it. Without these, humans can change into chimerical creatures that are a random combination of Spatterjay animals. Evolutionary effects of the virus on native life are most ably demonstrated in teleost forms such as the turbul.

However, the infected are actually named after Spatterjay's founder, "Spatter" Jay Hoop, and I'm not finding any references to green skin.

Comment: Going to buy the first one and see , thanks! I suspect it was from an earlier decade and iirc it was cheap and nasty paper , one of the novels u saw on spinny displays next to commando comics 8)